# Get file name of copied document off UIPasteBoard

Tags: ios, uipasteboard

I am trying to add a feature to an existing iOS app so that documents "copied" within Mail (say a PDF) can be pasted into my app.

After a PDF document is viewed in Mail and "Copy" chosen from the Action menu, within my app's code, when I inspect:

`[[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] items]`

I can see the document as per:

```
{
    "com.adobe.pdf" = {length = 875113, bytes = 0x25504446 2d312e35 0d0a25b5 b5b5b50d ... 300d0a25 25454f46 };
}
)
```

And further retrieve it via:

```
po [[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] valueForPasteboardType:@"com.adobe.pdf"]
<OS_dispatch_data: data[0x2820e5c00] = { leaf, size = 875113, buf = 0x1125e0000 }>
```

However, is there any way to get the document's name?  In the Files.app when I paste the same document it gets pasted as the original file name.

Should I be using the pasteboard for this, or if there another API which can get access to the copied document with the file name?

Answer (score 1):

Even if this question is a little older I happened to search for the same and finally found the solution. So for future reference:

Starting with iOS 11 `UIPasteboard` contains an array `itemProviders` which gives you all the information about the objects that are available. The same is used for Drag/Drop.

So with the following logic you can save the items to a certain path:

```
NSArray *items = [[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] itemProviders];
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < itemProvider.count; i++) {
    NSItemProvider *itemProvider = itemProvider[i];
    NSString *identifier = itemProvider.registeredTypeIdentifiers[0];
    [itemProvider loadDataRepresentationForTypeIdentifier:identifier completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        NSMutableDictionary *result;
        if (!error) {
            NSString *ext = (__bridge NSString *)(UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass((__bridge CFStringRef _Nonnull)(identifier), kUTTagClassFilenameExtension));
            if ([ext isEqualToString:@"jpeg"]) {
                ext = @"jpg";
            }
            NSString *mime = (__bridge NSString *)(UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass((__bridge CFStringRef _Nonnull)(identifier), kUTTagClassMIMEType));
            if (!mime) {
                 mime = @"application/*";
            }
    
            NSString *filename = itemProvider.suggestedName;
            NSString *path = [folderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
            [data writeToFile:path options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
        }
    }
}
```